# Edit column’s name in grid view that it binds with stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview

I have a grid view in asp.net that it binds with stored procedure like this:

```
con.Open();
 query = "getDataProfile";
 com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
 GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
 GridView1.DataSource = com.ExecuteReader();
 GridView1.DataBind();
 con.Close();
```

My stored procedure is :

```
create proc
[dbo].[getDataProfile]

as
select Pname,Pfamily,Pmobnum 
from Profile
```

My result is :

```
panme - pfamily , pmobnum

ana   - white   - 7686876
```

I’d like to change name of columns in grid view!
my target:

```
first name - last name - mobile

ana        - white     - 7686876
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gridview **AutoGenerateColumns** = false  and add **BoundField** to each column like this:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="panme" HeaderText="First Name"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pfamily" HeaderText="Last Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pmobnum" HeaderText="Mobile" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**DataField** is column name and **HeaderText** is column header.

***"Update : "***

Code behind:

```
con.Open();       
query = "getDataProfile";
com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
//-------
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
DataSet dset = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dset,"t1");
//--------
GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
var result = com.ExecuteReader();        
//GridView1.DataSource = com.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables["t1"];
GridView1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Comment: How can I show fixed count in grid view? I don’t show all data in a page, I want show 10 rows of grid view in a page!

Comment: but it throws an exception!

Comment: "The data source does not support server-side data paging."  I add  PageSize="5" too but exception persists.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it by

```
   GridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "first name";
```

and so on.

You can try this

```
void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.HeaderRow)
    {
      // use the index of your cell
      e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "first name";
    }

 }
```

Comment: It throws an exception!!

Comment: After binding data you should call it because before that there is no column in your gridview.

Comment: I called it after binding data.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 way

1. is change you select statement with following

```
    select 
        Pname as [first name],
        Pfamily as [last name],
        Pmobnum as [mobile]
    from 
        Profile
```

2.after grid DataBind function use for loop or `foreach for GridView.Columns` and change their respective names, for example

```
foreach (DataControlField gvc in GridView1.Columns)
{
    switch (gvc.HeaderText)
    {
        case "panme":
            gvc.HeaderText = "first name";
            break;
        case "pfamily":
            gvc.HeaderText = "last name";
            break;
        case "pmobnum":
            gvc.HeaderText = "mobile";
            break;
    }
}
```

You can achieve your functionality using either of this 2 way

Comment: This loop doesn’t work. Because count of column is zero!! (GridView1.Columns.Count)

Comment: I only define a simple grid view in aspx file. <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
Do I have to change this code?